# SQL Server where clause with two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use this query in my app

```
SELECT * 
FROM Vi_WebReport 
WHERE Legajo = ? AND ent >= ? AND ent >= ?
```

So, legajo its a number that identifies one person. And `ent` is a date. The query works ok, but when I want to select only one day like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Vi_WebReport 
WHERE Legajo = 1 AND ent >= 02/02/2017 AND ent >= 02/02/2017
```

The query returns no results.

Comment: is this sql server or mysql?

Comment: For one, you aren't only selecting one day.  You're repeating the `ent>=02/02/2017` section twice.  Secondly, you need to quote dates:  `ent >= '2017-02-02'`

Comment: Are you sure you want the comparison operators for `ent` to both be pointing in same direction?  (`>=`) ?

Comment: have you checked the data available for that day?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: What **datatype** is your `ent` column in the view/table ?? And why do you have the same condition (`ent >= ?`) twice in your statement??

Comment: I think your where statement looks like this `ent > ? AND ent < ?`  In this case a single date would give no results as described -- just change to `>=` and `<-`

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you sure you want the comparison operators for ent to both be pointing in same direction?
2. If you are trying to get all the records on a specific date, and the data in the table is date time data, that actually is stored with a time component, then you have to compare the database values with the time at midnight in the morning, and the time one tick before midnight that night, or with midnight the following morning.

`Where ent >= '02/02/2017' and ent <= '02/02/2017 23:59:59'`
or
`Where ent >= '02/02/2017' and ent < '02/03/2017'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was comparing only de date but i need to compare also the time.

The correct filter was:

**Where ent >= '02/02/2017 00:00:00' and ent <= '02/02/2017 23:59:59'**